# How to use the makefile to generate .elf, .bin and .hex files

Tags: stm32

I'm trying to use the makefile of [this project](https://github.com/ripxorip/stm32_usb_midi) to generate a .hex, .bin or .elf file and then send it to my board via st-link.

Problem, I don't understand how to use the makefile.
The author of the project says that I need to specify the firmware folder of my board in the makefile, but I don't know which line in the makefile to specify this?

Moreover, I don't even know which make command to execute to generate these 3 files.

```
# Sources

SRCS = main.c stm32f4xx_it.c system_stm32f4xx.c

# USB
SRCS += usbd_usr.c usbd_desc.c usb_bsp.c
SRCS += usbd_midi_user.c

# Project name

PROJ_NAME=stm32f4_usb_midi
OUTPATH=build

###################################################

# Check for valid float argument
# NOTE that you have to run make clan after
# changing these as hardfloat and softfloat are not
# binary compatible
ifneq ($(FLOAT_TYPE), hard)
ifneq ($(FLOAT_TYPE), soft)
override FLOAT_TYPE = hard
#override FLOAT_TYPE = soft
endif
endif

###################################################

BINPATH=~/sat/bin
CC=$(BINPATH)/arm-none-eabi-gcc
OBJCOPY=$(BINPATH)/arm-none-eabi-objcopy
SIZE=$(BINPATH)/arm-none-eabi-size

CFLAGS  = -std=gnu99 -g -O2 -Wall -Tstm32_flash.ld
CFLAGS += -mlittle-endian -mthumb -mthumb-interwork -nostartfiles -mcpu=cortex-m4

ifeq ($(FLOAT_TYPE), hard)
CFLAGS += -fsingle-precision-constant -Wdouble-promotion -DUSE_MIDI
CFLAGS += -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard
else
CFLAGS += -msoft-float
endif

###################################################

vpath %.c src
vpath %.a lib

ROOT=$(shell pwd)

# Includes
CFLAGS += -Iinc -Ilib/Core/cmsis -Ilib/Core/stm32
CFLAGS += -Ilib/Conf

# Library paths
LIBPATHS = -Llib/StdPeriph -Llib/USB_Device/Core
LIBPATHS += -Llib/USB_OTG -Llib/USB_Device/Class/midi

# Libraries to link
LIBS = -lm -lstdperiph -lusbdevcore -lusbcore -lusbdevmidi

# Extra includes
CFLAGS += -Ilib/StdPeriph/inc
CFLAGS += -Ilib/USB_OTG/inc
CFLAGS += -Ilib/USB_Device/Core/inc
CFLAGS += -Ilib/USB_Device/Class/cdc/inc
CFLAGS += -Ilib/USB_Device/Class/midi/inc

# add startup file to build
SRCS += lib/startup_stm32f4xx.s

OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

###################################################

.PHONY: lib proj

all: lib proj
    $(SIZE) $(OUTPATH)/$(PROJ_NAME).elf

lib:
    $(MAKE) -C lib FLOAT_TYPE=$(FLOAT_TYPE)

proj:   $(OUTPATH)/$(PROJ_NAME).elf

$(OUTPATH)/$(PROJ_NAME).elf: $(SRCS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LIBPATHS) $(LIBS)
    $(OBJCOPY) -O ihex $(OUTPATH)/$(PROJ_NAME).elf $(OUTPATH)/$(PROJ_NAME).hex
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary $(OUTPATH)/$(PROJ_NAME).elf $(OUTPATH)/$(PROJ_NAME).bin

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f $(OUTPATH)/$(PROJ_NAME).elf
    rm -f $(OUTPATH)/$(PROJ_NAME).hex
    rm -f $(OUTPATH)/$(PROJ_NAME).bin
    $(MAKE) clean -C lib # Remove this line if you don't want to clean the libs as well
```

Comment: Did you try to run it at all? If it builds OK you should automatically end up with elf hex and bin.

Comment: No I can't, eclipse doesn't detect it as an eclipse project, so I can't build it.
Unless there is another way to build it?

Comment: You can just create a new eclipse project with the files and compile it. Perhaps try directly with CubeIDE. The makefile project seems to use unix shell commands (pwd, rm) so it does not work natively under Windows as it is now, maybe work around those commands, or try under cygwin or linux.